# Copy n-elements of a list to a new list

Tags: c#, list, datagrid, copy

I have `List<Mail> mails` and want to copy the first 100 elements to a new list, because I want to display them in a datagrid. But `mails` could contain more than 9000 elements, so it would take way too long if I use `mails`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `List<T>` it's probably most efficient to use its built-in [`List<T>.GetRange(int index, int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx)

```
var result = mails.GetRange(0, 100);
```

This is liable to be more efficient than using Linq because the `List<>` implementation can make use of private data to optimise it.

The implementation goes like this (from Reflector):

```
List<T> list = new List<T>(count);
Array.Copy(this._items, index, list._items, 0x0, count);
list._size = count;
return list;
```

So that will be about as fast as it can be.

Comment: Ran a quick test and it was almost 12X as fast than Take but the bottleneck seemed to be the `ToList` conversion required when using `Take`. If the default IEnumerable result from Take is kept, it's faster than `GetRange` (but both ran sub 400ms, looping 1m times).

Comment: @keyboardP If you don't call `ToList()` on the Linq code, it won't actually be doing anything so it's bound to be faster.

Answer (score 6):

[LINQ Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
var first100Mails = new List<Mail>(mails.Take(100));
```